# MongoDB Timeout Query

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongoose, devops, query-timeout

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to apply a query timeout in the `script file` of MongoDB to prevent slow/idle/hanging requests.

I am referring https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.maxTimeMS/#examples documentation.

Now I am trying to write script as below for the `maxTimeMS` as below:-

```
#!/bin/bash
db.collection.find({ $query: {}, $maxTimeMS: 100 })
```

And it is giving an error:-

```
mongodb-timeout.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `{'
mongodb-timeout.sh: line 4: `db.collection.find({ $query: {}, $maxTimeMS: 100 })'
```

Does anybody have an idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think maxTimeMS is the curser option, not a system-wide variable. As you can see in their [jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13775) you might be able to write some script to achieve this.

Comment: I have edited the question and tried according to your comment. Could you please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need, is [mongodb Node.js driver documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#find). There is an option to set a timeout for particular query (i.e. cursor).

[cursor.maxTimeMS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.maxTimeMS/#cursor.maxtimems--) is a Mongo shell method which is different from Node.js (though both of them are javascript based).